# [Sonarqube][Java]Printf-style format strings should be used correctly

Tags: sonarqube

it seems that a new rule is available with latest version.
I have several issue reported as "Printf-style format strings should be used correctly (squid:S3457)"

I don't understand the description and what is wrong in [my case](https://sonarcloud.io/component?id=camel-lsp-server%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgithub%2Fcameltooling%2Flsp%2Finternal%2FAbstractLanguageServer.java&line=80):

```
LOGGER.info("Checking for client process pid: {0}", parentProcessId);
// issue: String contains no format specifiers
```

In the rules description we have:

```
java.util.Logger logger;
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Result {0}.", myObject.toString()); // Noncompliant; no need to call toString() on objects
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Result.", new Exception()); // compliant, parameter is an exception
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Result '{0}'", 14); // Noncompliant {{String contains no format specifiers.}}
```

and

```
java.util.Logger logger;
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Result {0}.", myObject);
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Result {0}'", 14);
```

What's the difference with my cases?
Can you help me understand what is the correct way to write it?

Comment: FYI @Aurelien I've swapped your issue link for the code itself + a link to the line of code because the issue will go away if you fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

understood my error, with slf4j logger, {} needs to be used instead of {0}

Answer (score 3):

Noncompliant Code Example

logger.info("Query: " , query);

LOGGER.info("Query: {0}", query);
// issue: String contains no format specifiers

Compliant Solution

LOGGER.info("Query: {}", query);